# Infragistics - Ultragrid - Group rows into categories

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I would like to group rows in categories like that:

[image: example]

I know how to do this with OutlookGroupBy but its not possible to put the same row into severals categories

So is there a way to group rows while beeing possible to put the same row into several categories at the same time?

My ultragrid is bound to a dataset

Answer (score 0):

First thing coming to mind is to add another table to your dataset and create category rows in the new table, then add a data relation between the two and use the category table as datasource for the grid.

Thus you effectively build your own "groupings". It's a little more work but my best guess to get the grid do this is to use creation filters - which would be a lot more difficult and time consuming.